# Specific question or generic question?

Tags: discussion, area-51

On Area 51, I thought that specific questions would be better, & I've been telling people as such:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4501/coffee/4507#4507

However, I notice that some proposals are using lots of generic questions with generic words in square brackets, like

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4799/bonsai-cultivation

Which one is better?

Comment: Also see my earlier question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52218/what-format-should-area-51-questions-take

Comment: @Popular Demand: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 6):

#### What's the purpose of asking the question?

The bracket notation is nice for the purpose of voting. It helps keep the focus on the *point* of the question rather than the semantics. In your example:

*"What procedure should I follow to brew the perfect espresso?"*

Is the *purpose* of the question to show that we talk about *espresso* or that the site includes talk about *brewing techniques?* I think the "brewing techniques" is more the point of the question so it might be clearer to write:

*"What procedure should I follow to brew the perfect [espresso]?*

...so people don't start harping on whether the site is about espresso or also cappuccino, latte, or ristretto.

#### Don't be *too* general

You *don't* want to use the bracket notation to *overly* genericize your question to the point of ambiguity (i.e. *How do I [do some thing] to that [device] to make it [work]?*)

#### Provide *specific* examples

In your second example:

*How do I get [species] seeds to germinate?*

I'm sure the author meant that bonsai germination is a valid topic but this isn't entirely clear and would have been better written:

*How do I get [shimpaku] seeds to germinate?*

Your site's FAQ (which comes later) should contain the proper, iconic words for your model questions (not this [bracket] stuff). So please provide an actual [example] that is fitting for your site. You want the experts to get excited about your site through the questions they see. A question like *"Does the SCAA Brew Chart need to be changed?"* is certainly going to attract more experts than *"Hey! Folgers is on sale at Shop Rite!"*

Comment: It strikes me that it might be a good idea to put [ ] with more than one alternative inside the brackets, like "How do I get [shimpaku/sakura] seeds to germinate?" Then people can see that it's meant to be a "framework for a question" rather than a real question. What do you think?

Comment: Use your best judgment. If one example is sufficient, use one. Don't add unnecessary examples if it doesn't add to the readability or clarity: *"How do you train a [dalmatian]?"* (good). *"How do you train a [dalmatian|beagle|shepherd|mutt]?"* (not as good).

Answer (score 3):

*What procedure should I follow to brew the perfect espresso?* might not prevent someone else from posting *What procedure should I follow to brew the perfect cappuccino?* to steal rep by splitting up the potential votes, so IMHO keeping the questions quite general now and refining them during commitment is better.