# Area 51 Group Development Syntax

Tags: discussion, area-51, definition-phase

During the defining phase of a new proposed group, is it preferable to post questions with a specific topic, or to generalize them to show the type of question you're implying?

Example 1 (for a geology group):

1. What do you study in seismology?
2. What do you study in [field area]?

Example 2:

1. How do you tell the difference between fools gold and real gold?
2. How do you tell the difference between [mineral A] and [mineral B]?

Example 3:

1. Where's a good place to go fossil hunting near Hartford?
2. Where's a good place to go fossil hunting near [wherever]?

Comment: See: [What's with all the \[brackets\] on Area51?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55203/whats-with-all-the-brackets-on-area51) and [What format should Area 51 questions take?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52218/what-format-should-area-51-questions-take) (short answer: don't do the "mad libs" thing. If you gotta use brackets, put something specific inside of them.)

Comment: Welcome to Meta, @tryaria!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the above.

Based on your examples, I would say:

> How do you tell the difference between [fools gold] and [real gold]?

The brackets denote that the question ISN'T trying to establish whether "gold" is a valid topic for the site. It establishes that the identification of minerals is on topic. The [bracket] notation simply indicates that the word can be replaced with *any* specific example. Including a specific example helps clarify the context of the question.

It also avoids numerous duplicates when the same question is asked with different specifics:

> How do you tell the difference between graphite and molybdenite?
>   Are amethyst and quartz the same thing?
>   What's the difference between alabaster and calcite?

Such duplicates are not helpful in defining the site.

Comment: Good answer! I hadn't thought of it that way. Much better than either option I had come up with. @ Robert