# How fine-grained should a proposed Site subject be?

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-proposal

Say I'm considering a proposal for Blender 3D modelling software - but is that too narrow a subject? Should the site be for 3D Modelling, and not one specific package? How do you determine the granularity of a site proposal?

Update - I realize that I'm taking my life in my hands, by disagreeing with people who have more karma than I'll ever see, but... :) I've read the comment-links (which are good, thanks), but I don't see how this is a duplicate *Question*.

Joel asked a very *general* Question, "how to make a successful proposal" - and then gave **four** distinct Answers, one of which was *pick the right scope*.

My question was, *How do I pick the right scope for a proposal?* Which was more specific, and, IMHO, not the same as his Question at all...

Yes, I now see that he (sort of) answered my Question, but it certainly wasn't in response to the same Question. Aren't Q/A supposed to be more single-Question/multiple *competing* Answers, also? Should his Answers be split into four Questions?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52066/what-makes-a-winning-site-proposal/52071#52071

Comment: Without any of the same words, this is a duplicate to the series of posts by Joel Spolsky: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52066/what-makes-a-winning-site-proposal. Read and understand what he wrote there and that will guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the comment links, the answer appears to be - "Don't make the site too small", and "Don't make the site too large". Uh, okay...

But Joel also says that the *users* should help out, by following proposals that have the *right* scope - which implies that I should go with whatever granularity I think fits best, and let the voting determine which is right.

So I guess the best answer for my *particular* proposal, is go with Blender - then if *someone else* proposes a 3D modelling site, and it gets more votes, then that site wins.

Comment: That's the point. It's not about "your site" winning, it's about "a site you proposed" being created and maintained by the community. So if the more general site wins, then so what.

Comment: @Earlz, yes I got that - maybe I should re-word my answer. My point was that part of determining the *scope* was to use the voting process, that I don't *have* to get the exact right scope.