# Separate Stack Exchange Network for SCADA

Tags: support, area-51, site-proposal

There are quite a few questions about SCADA/PLCs/HMI/DCS/controls currently on the Stack Overflow site, but I think it would make sense to give these topics their own separate site, as they're not really part of "general programming", more an offshoot of electrical engineering/controls.

Any suggestions on who I would talk to to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a better duplicate than one with -5 score?  Surely that has been asked in a better way at some point.

Comment: This one may be better: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52066/what-makes-a-winning-site-proposal

Comment: It isn't a real dupe of any of them because it is specific and those are general.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Regardless, the general answer still applies - post a proposal on A51.

Comment: @Iszi, yep, that's the answer.

Comment: I always use [How can I propose a new site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974/179419) @Mr.Wizard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know much about any of the topics you were talking about, but you could always try making a site suggestion on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), which is where all the new sites are borne from