# Any plans for a Turkish version of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, area-51, internationalization

Do Stack Overflow managers have any thoughts on launching a Turkish version of the site?

Comment: This will depend on all sorts of things - the biggest being the presence of a native Turkish speaker to be a community manager. If you see an advert for one of those then you know the site is getting ready for launch.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish) for it.

You can always commit to it (though, as it says on the page, is on hold while international features needed to make it functional are being added).

Comment: I'm wondering why it is removed from Area 51... Also, the questions I found when I searched on google to know what happened to it, are removed from Area 51. While "international features" are not needed to be made for some languages (spanish, portugees etc), it was needed for some other languages and after so many commitments, it is removed without any announcement. In wasn't fair enough for our stackoverflow community.

Comment: @Asqan see my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315477/289691)

Answer (score 2):

The Area 51 proposal referred on the [other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240274/289691) was deleted. Please checkout:

- [Internationalization 'State of the Stack' - Stack Overflow edition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20987/133145)

  - Tl;Dr: Area51 stop receiving new site proposals for non-English sites.
- [Changes to the Area 51 Process v3.0](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27938/133145)

  - Tl;Dr: Proposals that doesn't meet the requirements for new sites were deleted. The major assumption is that the community exists before the new site proposal and that community is committed to timely complete the new site proposal process. Related: [What makes a winning site proposal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52066/289691)

Comment: What does this mean? That there will be no Turkish stack exchange if its own?

Comment: @aesking This means that will not be a new fully localized non-English site for a while. When? AFAIK the company didn't say that yet.

Comment: is it not possible to create a Turkish language learning site that is in English. It seems it is [possible](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/since-se-s-decision-to-put-a-halt-on-non-english-language-based-ses-is-linguist); but not many have followed suit using this approach. Why?

Comment: @aesking This question isn't about language learning sites by the other hand I don't know the reason you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry, so it’s possible to create a Turkish stackexchange for the purpose of language learning, grammar but have it in English? This question is very misleading. I didn’t know it literally meant have the SE in “Turkish”.

Comment: This question is about having a Stack Overflow (programming) site in Turkish, not about one for learning Turkish. By the way if you want to make a new site proposal on Area 51 be sure to already have a community eager to have that site and are willing to participate on the proposal process.

Comment: @aesking If you are planning to make a new proposal checkout [What makes a winning site proposal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52066/289691) (Link just added to my answer)