# How is the decision made to add a new Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, area-51, stack-exchange, scope

I want to know how the decision to start a new Stack Exchange site is arrived at. What are the things considered before a new site is approved?

Why are there multiple sites for one set of things? For example Ask Ubuntu is separate from Unix / Linux. And so on...

Comment: Check out [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Checked out! I understand now!

Comment: Area 51 is not available in android app?

Comment: No, Area51 is running on an older version (as in antique) of the software  and so the api used by the mobile versions don't include Area51.

Comment: @rene is there any plans to update area 51's stack exchange version? Will it be available in android app if the version is updated?

Comment: No plans: Area 51 is not under active development. If it is ever replaced by something, the new thing will not be like Q&A sites, so it seems unlikely it would be accessible through the app. -- my interpretation of [Anna Lear's comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246503/area51-is-missing-from-the-combined-reputation-diagram-it-is-a-bug-or-feature#comment806944_246503)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Meta SE Q&A called [What makes a winning site proposal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52066/what-makes-a-winning-site-proposal) which discusses how Stack Exchange sites can go from conception to graduation.

I recommend reading [this answer from Joel Spolsky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52067/215590).