# Area51 is missing from the combined reputation diagram, it is a bug or feature?

Tags: bug, area-51, stackexchange.com, reputation-graph

Checking the [combined reputation diagram of the highest reputationed area51 user](https://stackexchange.com/users/1335/jmfsg?tab=reputation), we can find that his area51 history is entirely missing.

I have similar situation (my area51 reputation also stepped over 200 recently).

I think, generating the reputation diagram needs the daily log history of the SE sites, and it could be generated incompatible ways on area51.

Is it a bug, or an intended feature? Can we hope in the future it will be fixed?

Comment: That might be caused by the fact that Area51 is on a different (older?) code base that makes integrating it with SE wide features harder if not impossible.

Comment: @rene As I know, the changes of the main SE code base are merged monthly into area51.

Comment: Based on this [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52448/158100) you seem to be right about the monthly merges but the last paragraph sort of contradicts that. I recall a dev mentioned that A51 was better left untouched as much as possbile for all kind of reasons but I can't find the reference to back that statement ...

Comment: @rene I think, area51 may have some fallbacks regarding the interaction with the network-wide part of the system. Maybe they had to create some like a "least common denominator" of the currently existing SO sites (www.stackexchange.com, main SE sites, meta SE sites, area51, area51 discuss, data, career SE, and blog) and use them in an integrated form. Although it were a major refactoring of the current code base.

Comment: @PeterHorvath "As I know, the changes of the main SE code base are merged monthly into area51." -- Not even a little bit. We bolt some features (like the top bar) onto Area 51 when we have to, but not everything makes it in and certainly not on any sort of monthly schedule.

Comment: @AnnaLear I am sorry, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52448/158100) I've read that.

Comment: @PeterHorvath Ah yes, that was back when Stack Exchange was in its 1.0 days (which is more or less where Area 51 stayed, code-wise). Area 51 is no longer under active development, so it's not being kept in sync with the current Q&A codebase.

Comment: @AnnaLear Is there a plan for a feature synchronization in the future? Somewhere on discuss.area51 I've read from the plan of an "area52" site, but it was around 3 years before now. Anyways, discuss.area51 seems to me to a full-featured 2.0 site, if it was integrable with area51, why www.stackexchange.com isn't?

Comment: Whatever form Area 52 takes (if any), it's unlikely to be a port of our Q&A codebase. We made that mistake once already. :) No plans for feature sync right now that I know of.

Comment: @AnnaLear I am so sorry. Thank you the answers!