# What Stack Exchange sites are dedicated to a product or company?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

What's a list of Stack Exchange sites that are dedicated to a product or company? For example, [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) is dedicated to Apple. [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour) is dedicated to...well... Ubuntu. Are there any rules relating to the creation of Stack Exchange sites dedicated to products or companies?

Comment: "Is there any rules relating to the creation of SE sites dedicated to products or companies?" https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52067/375663 basically if you have enough people interested, you can make a site about anything AFAIU.

Comment: AU, Drupal, Craft CMS, etc. A lot to name in a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions at [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) place no restrictions on proposing the creation of SE sites dedicated to products or companies.

Those instructions should be read in conjunction with various ideas for [What makes a winning site proposal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52066/what-makes-a-winning-site-proposal) to decide whether a particular product or company may be suitable to propose an SE site dedicated to it.

I'll leave other answerers, or you, to go through the [list of all SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) to determine which, besides [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), are dedicated to a particular product or company.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say **a lot**, depending on the criterion of "dedicate to".

Here's a list of sites that "dedicate to" a specific product or products of a specific company.

- Android Enthusiasts - Android OS by Google
- Ask Different - All products of Apple
- Ask Ubuntu - Ubuntu OS by Canonical
- Augur - Augur by Forecast Foundation OU
- Blender - Blender (computer 3D software) by Blender Foundation
- CiviCRM - CiviCRM software
- Drupal Answers - Drupal CMS
- Emacs - Emacs editor
- ExpressionEngine® Answers - ExpressionEngine® CRM software
- Joomla! - Joomla CMS
- Magento - Magento eCommerce software platform
- Mathematica - Mathematica by Wolfram
- Meta Stack Exchange - Where people admires Jon Skeet
- Raspberry Pi - Raspberry Pi hardware by Raspberry Pi Foundation
- SharePoint - SharePoint my Microsoft
- Stack Apps - Same as Meta Stack Exchange
- Stack Overflow - For jQuery, a JavaScript framework that does everything
- Stellar - The Stellar Distributed Exchange
- Tor - The Tor network
- Vi and Vim - Vi and Vi IMproved text editor
- Windows Phone - Windows Phone and Windows Mobile OS by Microsoft
- elementary OS - elementary OS

Comment: You missed some: Arduino, Bitcoin, Bricks (aka LEGO), Craft CMS, Etherium, Iota, Monero, Wordpress Development... (Although the first three sites are a little broader than their namesakes.)